# How to do continue regex search, match n capture in one line

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to perform a continuous search in a line

```
  2012-15-08 07:05 *** Error importing row no. 5: The import of 785 line failed because of 345 item
```

I am trying to capture 3 numerals after matching on *row no., import of & because of* respectively.

I know how to search on first word but I am not able to continue on second (*import of)* in a single regex line

My code till now, give me first match on *row no*, how to continue with next word match in a single line

```
row no\. (\d+):
```

So expected output is something like, after matching on *row no., import of & because of*

```
 5  785  345
```

Comment: Try `([^\s\d]+\s+[^\s\d]+) (\d+)`, see https://regex101.com/r/7tlHh4/1

Comment: @rawrex that won't help my requirement

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it will only capture the numbers, I need to match first the words, then capture these numbers

Comment: That regex captures 2 words before the number into Group 1, and the number into Group 2. See https://ideone.com/mHPsre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
import re
txt = '2012-15-08 07:05 *** Error importing row no. 5: The import of 785 line failed because of 345 item'
regex = re.compile(r'row no\. \d+|import of \d{3}|because of \d{3}')
mo = re.findall(regex, txt)
```

**Output**

```
['row no. 5', 'import of 785', 'because of 345']
```

**Regex Explanation**

1st Alternative `row no\. \d+`

- `row no` matches the characters row no literally (case sensitive)
- `\.` matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
- matches the character   literally (case sensitive)
- `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
- `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

2nd Alternative `import of \d{3}`

- `import of`  matches the characters import of  literally (case sensitive)
- `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
- `{3}` matches the previous token exactly 3 times

3rd Alternative `because of \d{3}`

- `because of`  matches the characters because of  literally (case sensitive)
- `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
- `{3}` matches the previous token exactly 3 times

To achieve an output of just the numerals you can also use the `sub` method.

**Code**

```
import re
txt = '2012-15-08 07:05 *** Error importing row no. 5: The import of 785 line failed because of 345 item'
mo = re.sub(r'\D+', ' ', ''.join((re.findall(r'row no\. \d+|import of \d{3}|because of \d{3}', txt)))).strip()
print(mo)
```

**Output**

```
5 785 345
```

I've found this website useful when working with regex, [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not the most elegant one, but it works...

```
>>> s = "2012-15-08 07:05 *** Error importing row no. 5: The import of 785 line failed because of 345 item"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'[0-9]+', s.split('***')[1])
['5', '785', '345']
```

So, basically, we just split the string by `***` and get all integers from the right part of the string.